# How to apply attr_accessor for a variable in hash in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have some variables in a instance variable (for other methods can access the variable) which type is hash.

if I don't want all members in hash @iw2 applied attr_accessor

only @iw2[:dir] can be modified by others.

```
@iw2 ={}
@iw2[:dir] = "#{Rails.root}/#{ENV["module_handy_network_tools_src_path"]}"
@iw2[:prog_path] ="#{@iw2[:dir]}/#{ENV["module_handy_network_tools_prog_path"]}"
```

So I wrote that way,

```
attr_accessor :iw2[:dir]
```

But I got the error

```
TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):
  app/helpers/handy_network_tools_helper.rb:8:in `[]'
```

How to fix the problem, thanks in advance.

```
[2] pry(#<HandyNetworkToolsController>)> @iw2.class
=> Hash
```

Comment: I think `@iw2` is Array..thr error is telling that...can you check `puts @iw2.class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

When you find yourself having many methods with the same prefix (`iw2` in this case), it is a sign that there's a hidden object in there. How about this? Better?

```
class Iw2
  def initialize(hash)
    @dir = hash[:dir]
    @prog_path = hash[:prog_path]
  end

  attr_accessor :dir, :prog_path
end


class MyClass
  def initialize
    @iw2 = Iw2.new(:dir => "a rails path",
               :prog_path => "some another rails path")
  end

  delegate :dir, :prog_path, :to => :@iw2
end


mc = MyClass.new
mc.dir # => "a rails path"
mc.prog_path # => "some another rails path"
```

### Original answer

Well, `attr_accessor` doesn't work like that. You can always use old-fashioned getters/setters.

```
def iw2_dir
  @iw2[:dir]
end

def iw2_dir=(dir)
  @iw2[:dir] = dir
end
```

You can then implement your own `attr_sub_accessor` that will generate such methods for you.

```
attr_sub_accessor :iw2, :dir
attr_sub_accessor :iw2, :prog_path
```

(I think explicit getters/setters are better in this case)